# Join table with multiple column result in single Column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, conditional-statements

I have two table as 
Country table

```
id name 
1  Nepal
2  India
```

Salary Table

```
id  Countryid termid amount
1    1         1      100
1    1         2      500
3    2         1      200
4    2         2      400
```

i want result as

```
CountryName basicSalary  allowance
Nepal       100          500
India       200          400
```

Here term 1 is basic salary and 2 is allowance

Comment: Will`term` have only 1 and 2?

Comment: yes term have 1 and 2  @Viki888

Comment: Join Salary table twice, or do a group by.

Comment: how can i do this in condition @jarlh

Comment: @manoj, look at Viki888's answer below. Probably the best way to do this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join the table twice (use aliases)

```
select c.name as CountryName, 
       s1.amount as basicSalary
       s2.amount as allowance
from Country c
left join Salary s1
on s1.countryid=c.id
and s1.termid = 1

left join Salary s2
on s2.countryid=c.id
and s2.termid = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below query

```
SELECT c.name, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.termid = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) basicSalary, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.termid = 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) allowance 
FROM Country c
JOIN Salary s on c.id = s.Countryid
GROUP BY c.name;
```

Hope this would help you out.